# Find string that minimizes the sum of the edit distances to all other strings in set

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, strings, string-metrics

I have a set of strings $S$ and I am using the edit-distance ([Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) to measure the distance between all pairs.

Is there an algorithm for finding the string $x$ which minimizes the sum of the distances to all strings in $S$, that is

$\arg_x \min \sum_{s \in S} \text{edit-distance}(x,s)$

It seems like there should, but I can't find the right reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is known as "[median string problem](http://www.lirmm.fr/~rivals/PUBLI/FILES/MedianeCentreCPM03.pdf)" and it is NP-complete; some results can be found [searching with Google](http://www.google.it/search?q=levenshtein%20distance%20find%20%20median%20string); in particular "[2-Approximation Algorithms for Median and Centre String Problems](http://solomon.ipv6.club.tw/Research/Publication/median.ps)". If $x$ must be one of the points in $S$ then the problem becomes solvable in polynomial time.